# How to prevent seeking video with multiple videos on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I'm creating page with multiple videos on it, but I need to prevent seeking on them. I've found some ideas but they are working by ID of element and I need it to work with class (there are different amount on videos, depends on user, so I can't hard code it) and I would like to avoid jQuery solutions.

Comment: Please try to explain the issue in detail. It's not clear what you need actually

Comment: Yeah, I need to prevent user from changing time in video, I want him to watch all video from the beggining to the end. And I've got multiple videos like that on one page. It's not 1 video per page

Comment: Can you send me the sample page? I think you can hide the controls on the video

Comment: Yeah, I can hide them, but i still need fullscreen button, and if i hide controls i hide it

Comment: Please send me the sample page or code snippet